# Graphite and Elasticsearch db correlation

Tags: elasticsearch, graphite, grafana

On one hand, I've been using Graphite (with whisper) for some time already. I parse data with grafana.

On the other hand, I've been logging TBs of logs through logstash (with an Elasticsearch output) for appliances and other system events.

Now I'd like to come up with correlations in between DBs. Any suggestions?

Could it be possible to log graphite events through ES?

Answer (score 1):

v2 of [grafana](http://grafana.org/) allows you to add [annotations](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/annotations/) to your graphite metrics. These can now come from elasticsearch based on a lucene search you define which can use any template variables you have defined in the dashboard.